# Javascript Can't read second element of array that is array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access all elements of my array except the first one but i get empty values.

```
renderTableBody = thisService => {
  console.log(thisService); // in the image it's the printed array
  console.log(thisService.length); // in the image is the number 1

  return thisService.slice(1).map(item =>
    item.map(k => (
      <TableRow key={k.kpiId}>
        <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
          {k.kpiId}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.kpiName}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.targetDisplay}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.targetDisplay}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.reason}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.action}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.dueDate}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.owner}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))
  );
};
```

When i log the length of array it prints 1 when it actually has 2 elements. When i try to access only the second element of the array, i get "undefined".

This is the logged to console object: 
[image: capture]

Am i doing something wrong in accessing the second element of my array which is an array itself?

**EDIT**
The part of code where i am calling the function renderTableBody:

```
<div id="servicesInputs">
    {kpiServInputs.map((service) => (
        <div key={service[0].id} id={service[0].id}>
            <div align="left">
                <h4>{service[0].serviceName}</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Paper >
                    <Table>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell align="left">#</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">KPI</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Target</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Actual</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Reason</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Action</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Due Date</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">Owner</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {this.renderTableBody(service)}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </Paper>
            <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you only trying to print out the values from the array found at `thisService[1]`?

Comment: I'm guessing the array is populated asynchronously?

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(thisService))`. If you hover over that `i` in the blue box, you'll find that it shows the most recent value of the variable, not the value at the time it was logged.

Comment: What does shows the "i" icon near to the array console.log? pretty sure that there's a differene between the array of the virtual DOM of React, and the loaded in the actual DOM

Comment: @pmiranda it says "Value below was evaluated just now"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the array was populated asynchronously with making a `fetch` call to an `api`. What worked for me was making the return async and waiting the `fetch` call to finish and then populating the array.

The code:

```
function fetchKpiServicesInputs(state) {
    let serviceInputs = [];
    return async dispatch => {

    for (var i = 0; i < servicesCount; i++) {
        let newServ = [];
        newServ.push({id: i, serviceName: kpiServices[i].name });

        let url = "apiUrl";
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET'
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        if (Object.keys(responseData).length > 0) {
            newServ.push(responseData);
        }
        serviceInputs.push(newServ);
    }
    dispatch(receiveKpiServiceInputs(serviceInputs));
};
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
renderTableBody = thisService => {
  console.log(thisService); // in the image it's the printed array
  console.log(thisService.length); // in the image is the number 1

  return thisService[1].map(item =>
    item.map(k => (
      <TableRow key={k.kpiId}>
        <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
          {k.kpiId}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.kpiName}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.targetDisplay}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.targetDisplay}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.reason}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.action}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.dueDate}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{k.owner}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))
  );
};
```

This should be your code because as @Dupocas pointed out, `thisService` is an array that looks like `[{Object}, [Array]]`.

When you run `slice` on this and a `map` on the result, what you are doing is trying to map through the outer array of something like `[['stuff you need']]`. This outer array has a length of 1 and would act exactly as you are seeing it act. By changing the `slice` to directly access the first index of `thisService`, you will be looping though the info you need.

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". It doesn't recognise the second element of the outer array

Comment: Just noticed you have 3 console logs in the image. What is the first: `(5) [Array]...` and second: `[{...}]` as there are only 2 `console.log`s in your code

Comment: the `thisService` array is element of another array, which is the one you see logged `(5) [Array]`

Comment: so `thisService == [{...}]`? Or asked a little better, `thisService` is an array with a single JS object inside it?

Comment: It's the object you can see in the picture that i have expanded. It has one json object and another array of elements.

Comment: `thisService.slice(1)` on an array of length 1 would return an empty array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196158/discussion-between-e-hysenaj-and-adr5240).